# When can we use direct substitution in limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

I know that we can use direct substitution if we have a limit of some polynomial or rational function, e.g., 
$$
\lim_{x\to 1} x^2-3x+1 = \lim_{x\to 1} (1^2-3 \times 1+1) = -1.
$$ Also I came across with the limit below which the book uses direct substitution:

$$
\lim_{x\to 1} \ln\left(\frac{5-x^2}{1+x}\right) 
 = \lim_{x\to 1}\ln\left(\frac{5-1^2}{1+1}\right) 
 = \lim_{x\to 1}\ln\left(\frac{4}{2}\right) 
 = \ln2.
$$

So, what is the idea? When can I use direct substitution?

Comment: When "it works". (I.e. wherever you are not at a singularity or an indeterminate form.)

Comment: What can we say formally?

Comment: When $x$ belongs to the domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use substitution to the limit towards one point whenever the function is continuous at that point, that's one of the definituons of continuity.

Comment: What can we do when there are some discontinuities?

Comment: When there are discontinuities yiu can't use direct evaluation for example with $f (x) = 1/x $ when x tends to zero, you can't substitute 1/0 (at least not formally) but you have to take lateral limits or use other rules like L'Hôpital's or limit tricks like factorizating.

Comment: So, what can we say formally about when to use direct substitution?

Comment: When the function is continuos at the point.

Comment: If we do not know whether it is continuous or not, what can we say in this case?

Comment: When the function is not continuos at the point you can't get the limit by direct substitution.